# jQuery datepicker doesn`t validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a problem with my jQuery datepicker.
If I sumbit the form without a value in the datepicker, it tells me to enter a date.
When I do pick a date it's like its not getting updated, and still want me to enter a date.

Look at this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/xa5gn1kq/12/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#rental-form").bootstrapValidator({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        live: 'enabled',
        submitButtons: 'button[id="rental-submit"]',
        fields: {
            datePicker: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Velg en dato'
                    },
                    date: {
                        format: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
                        message: 'Datoen er ikke i riktig format, velg fra listen - eller skriv i følgende format: mm-dd-yyyy'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $('#datePicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        minDate: "0",
        endDate: "01-01-2016",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        autoclose: true,
        onSelect: function (date, inst) {
            $('#data').text(this.value);
            $('#rental-form').formValidation('revalidateField', 'datePicker');
        }
    });
});
```

Try submitting without a date, then choose a date and see that the validation error isn't removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `formValidation` plugin, it's still called `bootstrapValidator` in the datePicker code

```
$('#datePicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
    minDate: "0",
    endDate: "01-01-2016",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    autoclose: true,
    onSelect: function (date, inst) {
        console.log('ccc')
        $('#data').text(this.value);
        $('#rental-form').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'datePicker');
    }         //              ^^ here, wrong name !
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xa5gn1kq/13/)